# How to check if `<nowait>` mapping option is available for current VIM installation?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript

I just realized some `<nowait>` maps I have in my `.vimrc` were being silently ignored on an installation of VIM on a remote server that I'm using.

How can I check whether the `<nowait>` option is available at all, and skip those sections of my `.vimrc` if it is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<nowait>` was added in version 7.3.1261.  You can check for at least this version using:

```
if v:version > 703 || v:version == 703 && has("patch1261")
   ...
endif
```